# Ember.js with Cloudkit JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, cloudkit

I have built a small prototype project using CloudKit JS and am now starting to build the next version of it and am wanting to use Ember as I have some basic experience with it. However, I am not too sure where to place the CloudKit JS code. For example where should I add the configure part and the auth function? I think that once I find the spot for the auth code, I could then add some of my query functions into the individual views and components, right?

Here is my configure code (with the container and id removed):

```
CloudKit.configure({
containers: [{

  containerIdentifier: '###',

  // @todo Must generate a production token for app store version
  apiToken: '###',

  auth: {
    persist: true
  },

  // @todo Must switch to production for app store version
  environment: 'development'
}]
});
```

Here is the auth function:

```
function setupAuth() {

  // Get the container.
  var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();

  //Function to call when user logs in
  function gotoAuthenticatedState( userInfo ) {

    // Checks if user allows us to look up name
    var userName = '';
    if ( userInfo.isDiscoverable ) {
      userName = userInfo.firstName + ' ' + userInfo.lastName;
    } else {
      userName = 'User record name: ' + userInfo.userRecordName;
    }

    //Calls out initialization function
    init();

    //Sets up UI for logged in users
    setAuthenticatedUI( userName );

    //Register logged out function
     container
      .whenUserSignsOut()
      .then( gotoUnauthenticatedState );
  }

  //Function to call when user logs out
  function gotoUnauthenticatedState( error ) {

    //Checks if error occurred
    if ( error && error.ckErrorCode === 'AUTH_PERSIST_ERROR' ) {
      displayError( logOutError, 'Error code: AUTH_PERSIST_ERROR' );
    }

    // Sets up the UI for logged out users
    setUnauthenticatedUI();

    //Register logged in function
    container
      .whenUserSignsIn()
      .then( gotoAuthenticatedState )
      .catch( gotoUnauthenticatedState );
  }

  // Check a user is signed in and render the appropriate button.
  return container.setUpAuth()
    .then( function( userInfo ) {

      // userInfo is the signed-in user or null.
      if ( userInfo ) {
        gotoAuthenticatedState( userInfo );
      } else {
        gotoUnauthenticatedState();
      }
    });
}
```

The init() then calls functions to setup the queries to adds a chart to the page using records. The setAuthenticatedUI() and setUnauthenticatedUI() functions simply apply and remove classes once the user has been authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer pretty much depends on the version of Ember you're using and if how you are planning on using it. With routes? Simple routes? RouteHandlers?

For example, if you are at Ember v2.3.0, you could consider using dependency injection (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/applications/dependency-injection/) to provide a configured container instance to the rest of your app, e.g.:

```
export function initialize(application) {
  var container = CloudKit.configure(config).getDefaultContainer();

  application.register('ckcontainer:main', container);
  application.inject('route', 'ckcontainer', 'ckcontainer:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'ckcontainer',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Then in a route, you can obtain a reference like so:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  activate() {
    // The ckcontainer property is injected into all routes
    var db = this.get('ckcontainer').privateCloudDatabase;
  }
});
```

-HTH